# What should I do when I see a question asking for the solution to homework?

Tags: discussion, homework

Very recently (as in seconds ago) I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932322/java-loops-help-please). The question, if it gets deleted, spelled out a problem, and asked for the solution. I understand that it's (or used to be) perfectly acceptable to ask for help with homework, so long as you showed your effort so far and explained what your problem was. Notice that this question is posted by someone who, if they've made effort at all to solve the problem, didn't bother posting it.

I've read around and, according to some comments (I forgot where, sorry) I should just answer it. In addition, the [How to ask a good question article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) no longer mentions that we should try to make an effort at all, which seems extraordinarily odd, since no one will learn to program from being spoon-fed the answers, and it's doubtful that anyone will be helped by it. However, looking at the close reasons, there doesn't seem to be a `too specific` reason anymore, either, which is equally confusing.

To get to the point, in this situation, what should I do? Should I vote to close with custom text? Should I just answer it? Should I downvote and move on?

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: Moments after posting this, I saw [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/248725), which doesn't quite cover it -- as everything else, it says that it's fine as long as you make some attempt yourself.

Comment: "What should I do when I see a question asking for the solution to homework?" - Give them the wrong answer. SCR

Comment: @Joe It pretty much is, actually. I haven't yet seen it. Apologies.

Comment: Pretend it's not a homework question, as that has no real bearing on how you answer it.  If it's a good question, it's a good question.  If it's a bad question, it's a bad question.  That someone's question is related to homework doesn't turn a good question into a bad question.

Comment: @Servy So what should I do for that question? There doesn't seem to be a close reason for it.

Comment: By the way, [this is the help section you were looking for.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Check down under "Some questions are still off-topic" and at item number 3.

Comment: @Kendra Ah, that's what it was. I didn't see it before.

Comment: Close it as off-topic, unclear what you're asking. I often refer the poster to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and explain *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Copying and pasting your assignment here does not count as "work you've done so far".*

Comment: Per what to close it under: I personally, had I looked at it sooner, would've flagged as "Unclear" because the formatting is so horrible that the text itself is hard to decipher to pull out the actual question. On top of that, it's not really a question but a "I need this here are my requirements write it please" type of request.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Too Broad is generally appropriate for questions of the form "[requirements dump] how do I do this?"

Comment: @KenWhite But it's not unclear at all. It's perfectly clear what they're asking, but it's not making any effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @Servy Is it too broad, though? It's a specific question. I think we need a new close reason that is specific for, or at least covers, not doing your own research. I could be wrong, though; I'm only just getting back into the site after a year or so gone.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes bear in mind what Servy said initially.  Homework does not have special rules.  That phrase in the help center exists to to serve as guidance for those users who want to ask for homework help.  If the question is clear, reasonably scoped, and answerable, then it is fine.  If it isn't, then it is not.

Comment: No. Read the description of "unclear what you're asking", which asks for more details. Also see "too broad", which asks for it to be narrowed in scope to a specific problem. Either may apply, depending on exactly how the question is asked.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I know, but aside from having no effort and bad formatting, it isn't a bad question. If someone said "I need to write a Java servlet that fetches data from an SQL database then prints it in this format", that might not be homework, but even if they describe in detail what they want done and are very clear about it, it's still showing no effort.

Comment: @KenWhite See my reply to psubee2003 -- I doubt that every question ever with no effort will fall under "unclear" or "too broad".

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I don't really know Java, but I think such a question is too broad.  It covers a lot of ground and could have any number of different solutions.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes If a question that shows no effort is not unclear or too broad (Doesn't lack detail but also isn't a "Please write an entire program for me" request) then the most it warrents is a downvote. This question was not that: It's asking for an entire homework assignment to be done, which is too broad to most, and is horribly formatted and hard to read, which makes it a bit unclear. As a Java programmer, I had to take more than a minute to decipher that question, which is far too long and makes it unclear in my book, given its short length.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Not really. Most of the solutions are just rephrasings of the original one. It's a specific problem with at most two unique answers, which I consider specific enough for SO. And that's if you're stretching and count two types of loop as separate answers.

Comment: @Kendra I'll do that from now on, then. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I fail to see why you asked for advice here, and then choose to argue or debate every one you receive. A copy/paste of an entire homework assignment, with no effort to solve it, is simply a "write my code for me" question, is too broad in scope (and/or unclear, as I've mentioned before), and I'm absolutely certain that the professor/instructor/teacher that assigned it is not interested in seeing **our work** to solve it. I'm also quite convinced that we don't need any more copy/paste graduates in the job market.

Comment: @Kendra  I honestly would probably up-vote the question that you had just described.  If all the good things that people usually associate with "effort" are there, with ho actual sign of effort,  than it's still a great question

Comment: @KenWhite I was confused as to why I was told to close it as "too broad" or "unclear". After rereading my question, I realize I worded it badly, but I was using that question as an example of what I meant by no-effort. I wasn't specifically asking about that question, but about that class of questions. I agree that no professor wants to see our work, but my question wasn't about that. It was about how I should signal that, and my confusion about what flag to use with it, since there aren't any that fit that hypothetical question.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes so what?  Effort is not important.  It's the results of that effort that are important.  It's the ways that it helps you answer the question that's important.  It's kinda like money.  The **only** reason why you would ever need money is because of the things that it buys.  If you were able to obtain those things without the money, then the money becomes worthless

Comment: @SamIam Then we're never going to agree. If you simply don't see effort as important, then this entire question becomes meaningless, because its central point is, to you, based on an invalid assumption. To me, on the other hand, effort is important -- if you literally put zero effort into solving a problem, instead doing nothing but pasting your assignment, in my mind, that's a bad SO question.

Comment: @SamIam: I totally disagree that effort isn't important. If the poster isn't willing to put in effort to solve the problem, they're clearly not attempting to learn anything. This site should *never* become a site for "Here are my needs. Write my code for me" types of questions, because there is absolutely *no value* in those questions for future readers. This isn't a "do my work for me" place; it's a *collection of knowledge* that can be *applied* to solve a problem - it's not a collection of "copy/paste your solution to everything".

Comment: @SamIam But you just said that a specific, detailed question, even if there's no effort, is a good one. ...Can we just agree to kinda disagree, and leave it at that? I've honestly completely lost track of this, and I need to stop having a headache if I'm to be productive at all today.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree that this should be a collection of knowledge.  but that would be a quality of the content.  Effort is a quality of the OP.  While Effort might cause good content, It isn't itself a component of content in general(good or bad).  People are getting too carried away with judging the OP, and they're not focusing enough on the content.

Comment: @Sam: I'm referring specifically to the question linked from here, and to the "Here's my homework. It's due tomorrow. Can you give me an answer URGENTLY!!!!!" type questions we see here around this time of the year. I don't particularly care who posts it or how long they've been here; it's a poor question that has no value for others (except maybe classmates of the person who copy/pasted it here).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes looks like you have your answer... but maybe this would help you..... do answers to the question, exactly as worded, help anyone else (who is not taking the same class).  If so, then it **might** be valuable.  Focus less on the origin and focus more on the quality of the question.  If the question is clear and understandable, and potential answers to the question are valuable and would help many other (who aren't taking the same class), then it the question is probably ok.  Why deprive people of answers just because you dislike the fact that someone is getting help with homework?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes the question posted here has problems, It's too broad and not entirely clear, but "not enough effort" is not one of the actual problems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close it as too broad.

- Asking Stack Overflow users to code up your entire program, and then explain literally  everything they did in a way that the OP is likely to understand is actually a surprisingly large task, therefore, the question is **too broad**.

Comment: "... in a way that the OP is likely to understand" -- figuring out where even to start may be a tall task. "Do you understand enough English to follow the explanation? ... Okay, I'll take that as a 'no'. Well, [A is for Apple, and they sell the Mac. 'B' is for Balls, which you might want to check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BELlZKpi1Zs)."

Comment: @Jongware That was kinda the point.  You might literally have to being by explaining the core concepts of computing as thought you were teaching an intro to CS class