# How to deal with users asking for homework help

Tags: discussion, questions, education

**NOTE: Not a duplicate of [Stack Overflow and homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions)** - I'm asking about how best to help, not if we can help.

What is the best way to help someone who needs homework help, but has not put in the time to understand the code? To be clear, **they have a specific technical question and need help, but their example is almost exclusively from example code- they don't seem to have any real understanding of the language or what they need. They are basically saying, 'I need a program/function that does X and I don't know how to build it, but I have some example code that I think is related.'**

Additionally, the user might include comments that show they have not spent any time learning- they just need need an answer now for class and have been copying and pasting examples with little understanding of the language at hand.

What is the best route we can take to help such users? How can we act as good guides and helpful teachers in these cases?

Comment: Are you asking something different than [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions)?

Comment: Or [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions)?

Comment: Or http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216577/135695

Comment: Your question rests on an unproven premise -- which is partly addressed by the question you've linked -- that "help[ing] such users...act[ing] as good guides and helpful teachers" **is** a goal of the site. This [has been discussed before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/603977). Related reading at [Yet another disgruntled new user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268099), [Are we being "elitist"? Is there something wrong with that?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262446) and the mammoth [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when I see a question asking for the solution to homework?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283410/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-question-asking-for-the-solution-to-homework)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing you can do is recognize that answering will not help them learn, and link them to

- [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/7757)

so that they can understand this as well.  Some highlights of that post:

> There are several things to consider as to why this is bad.
>
> The typical class builds upon previous experiences. The compiler class
>   has machine language and data structures as prerequisites because if
>   you don't understand those, you will be hopelessly lost in the class
>   and not even able to understand the lectures.
>
> Lets assume you do understand the code (the person answering the
>   question did a good job explaining it)... the curriculum is designed
>   to take you from A to Z with 24 steps between. As industry programmers
>   we often take short cuts and don't need say, steps ijkl to do
>   something. Learning from us, you'll never get these steps. However you
>   may find in your next assignment or class that understanding jk is
>   assumed and critical to the understanding of some other concepts. Just
>   because we don't need ijkl to do it doesn't mean it isn't understood.

Answer (score 5):

We don't care if it is homework or not. If it is a good question that asks a specific questions about a programming problems, that is fine.
And if it is "do my work for me" it isn't welcome.